# makefile: user function (macro) ifeq does not work as expected

Tags: if-statement, makefile, macros

**OBSOLETE: not of interest anymore.**

I am trying to validate and choose the execution path of a makefile macro using **ifeq** makefile conditional...

I am using makefiles inside mingw and a very old version of make (3.79.1) but the build system cannot be altered to update to the latest make version.

I am sending parameters to the user function and based on these parameters I would like to evaluate the execution path:

```
define CHECK_FILE
if ($(1),))
$(error Empty file provided to check! - $(1))
endif

ifeq ($(wildcard $(1)),)
$(error Invalid file provided for checking (file does not exist)! - $(1)!)
endif

ifeq ($(2),SPEED)
$(ROOT_PATH)/Tools/testSpeed.exe $(1)
else ifeq ($(2),ENDURANCE)
$(ROOT_PATH)/Tools/testStability.exe $(1)
else ifeq ($(2),MEMORY)
$(ROOT_PATH)/Tools/check_leaks.exe 8079 $(1)
else
$(error Bad test provided - $(2)!)
endif

endef
```

The problem is that I always get the "Empty file provided to check! - ..." error.. What am I doing wrong?

I can`t even add an echo in this macro.... it simply won`t print out anything! so that`s all about debugging...

Given my current experience - I hate gnu make and msys/mingw with each and every cell of my body... I appreciate any help to avoid hating it in the future.

The macro is called from several places, including lots of foreach loops:

```
someTArget:
    @$(foreach outFile,$(INCLUDED_FILES),$(call CHECK_FILE,$(FILE_OUT_PATH)/$(outFile),MEMORY))
    @$(foreach outFile,$(BUILT_BIN_FILES),$(call CHECK_FILE,$(FILE_OUT_PATH)/$(outFile),ENDURANCE))
    @$(foreach outFile,$(BUILT_BIN_FILES),$(call CHECK_FILE,$(FILE_OUT_PATH)/$(outFile),SPEED))
```

using MSDOS batch files in msys/mingw/make would not work as it does not see the parameters %1...%n and can`t evaluate environment variables.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you pare this down to an [MCVE](/help/mcve) please?  If there are a dozen calls and only one of them is failing, it is likely that it is not among the three you posted as a sample.

Comment: Your first conditional says `if` not `ifeq` which would trivially explain the trouble you are having. Voting to close as simple typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final 'enddef' should be written 'endef'. 
See GNU documentation here : [GNU make - Defining](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_node/make_68.html)

Something else : at the line

```
foreach external,$(INCLUDED_FILES),$(call CHECK_FILE,$(FILE_OUT_PATH)/$(outFile),MEMORY))
```

You refer to 'outFile' but you var is 'external'.

Comment: that`s a typo, sorry. corrected.

Comment: You may be referring to the wrong var, see my edited answer. Could you try echoing the same value with another foreach before these three ? By example :
@$(foreach external,$(INCLUDED_FILES),echo $(FILE_OUT_PATH)/$(external);)

Comment: Yes, that I have checked and all is ok. The problem is the ifeq`s inside the define... I took a raincheck, aborted this solution, now calling batch files from make files.. the build system is simply too old...... (16-years old, using make from 16 years ago...)

Comment: The "outFile" vs "exterma;" is also a typo. Due to the nature of my job (DARPA) I could not post exact code and I renamed lots of terms inside. Other foreach loops are consistent. Sorry for the misleading mistake, it would have first popped in my eyes / on the screen.

Comment: What about the other typo I pointed out this morning, in a comment to the question itself?

Comment: That may be a good point. Yet, I have tried removing first two ifs and the last one simply blasts off in the error as well. Thank you for your contribution, you may vote to close this question as it is now obsolete. Eventually I could try and create a simple script which does the very same as my script and post my findings. However, I am more convinced that the age of my tools is the root cause of this problem (using today`s articles and manuals for a 16-years old software version..). I will post some screenshots on my next question with the script and its execution result, I am too angry now.

Comment: Well, that's something I've never done in my makefiles but I tried a simple makefile with an ifeq($(1),) condition inside of a define FOO_FUNCTION and all I got was a fail from make with the message "The system cannot find the file specified" on the ifeq line. I suppose this is somehow not supported by make. I'm running mingw-make's latest stable version.